# How can I store a link into a velocity varible and display it in html?

Tags: java, html, css, velocity

This is the way I'm doing it but apparently it's wrong:

```
#set( $product_link = 'https://www.viator.com/tours/x/x-x/d0-22869ALHAMBRAEXC')
<p> Link: $product_link </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
#set( $product_link = 'https://www.viator.com/tours/x/x-x/d0-22869ALHAMBRAEXC')
<p> <a href="$link">Link</a> </p>
```